# creation of pdf using iText in java

Tags: java, swing, itext

I downloaded the iTextpdf-5.1.0 and I added it into the library of my project.

```
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

    /**
    * First iText example: Hello World.
     */
   public class Testcase {

    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
      public static final String RESULT= "E:/hello.pdf";

     /**
      * Creates a PDF file: hello.pdf
      * @param    args    no arguments needed
      */
      public static void main(String[] args)
       throws DocumentException, IOException {
        new Testcase().createPdf(RESULT);
       }

     /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
      * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException 
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3:gives error as no suitable method
    document.open();
    // step 4
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
    }
   }
```

At the step 3: it gives me the following error: `no suitable method found for getInstance()`.
Why this error occurs? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Version 1.5 ? Is it me or is that older than necessary ? I see no reason to use version older than 2.1.7 and current version is 5.3.1.

Comment: sorry i m using version 5.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using iText - 7.1.3. It worked for me.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {           

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("/home/users/Documents/pdf/hello_world.pdf"));
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));                      
        pdfDoc.addNewPage();            
        doc.close();

        } catch(SvgProcessingException e ){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch (Exception e) {         
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

> Here added the jar files that I used. I think this may help you.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
      </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/layout -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
public static void createPdf() throws DocumentException, IOException {

    File f = File.createTempFile("test", ".pdf");

    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));
    // step 3:gives error as no suitable method
    document.open();
    // step 4
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

So I would assume the problem is something with your filename, because that's the only part I changed. try to use *E:\hello.pdf* (with backslash) and make sure the JVM has write access in that location.

If that does not fix your problem, please provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. The only change I have to do is **output file name** 
i.e.     `public static final String RESULT = "C:\\hello.pdf";` Output file name needs escape character "\" .

I tested with **itextpdf-5.3.2.jar**.

try this.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * First iText example: Hello World.
 */
public class CreatePdf2 {

    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "C:\\hello.pdf";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF file: hello.pdf
     * 
     * @param args
     *            no arguments needed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
            IOException {
        new CreatePdf2().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * 
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException,
            IOException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        // step 3:gives error as no suitable method
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
}
```